# Google Auto Complete Does Not Return Results in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

In my app I'm trying to add a feature that would allow users to change their location by entering an address that utilizes the google autocomplete and utilize that to move the camera to the location. I am doing this by using flutter_google_places. I get the google search screen when I tap into my searchbox but, nothing returns. Here is my code:

```html
  Widget _buildSearchField() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 350,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: Colors.white),
          child: EnsureVisibleWhenFocused(
              focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
              child: TextField(
                controller: _emailController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.search),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      color: Colors.teal,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: "Find Where Can You Go?",
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                    fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                    filled: true),
                maxLines: null,
                onTap: () async {
                  Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                      context: context, apiKey: gKey);
                  displayPrediction(p);
                  print(p);
                },
              )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


  Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
          await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);


      double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

      print(lat);
      print(lng);
      print(address);
    } else {
      print('Not working');
    }
    return;
  }
```

I'm not sure what I missed here to return a result from the search input.

Comment: Check this issue (https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_google_places/issues/51) related to access to api being denied. Hope it helps.

Comment: did your developer account billing enable?

Comment: No. I don't think so. Why would that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud offers a $300 free trial that applies toward the first billing account you create. Since you've mentioned that you've not enabled your billing account, your issue might fall in the section mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing-and-pricing/billing):

> On or before the free trial ends, you must upgrade your first Cloud
> Billing account to a paid account to avoid any disruptions to your
> Google Maps Platform usage

That's why you might observed that it doesn't return anything because there is a requirement to enable your account.